# Why the cross validation loss is not decreasing for this model?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

Github link to code-
https://github.com/abhijit1247/Resnet50_trial1.git

I am trying to use transfer learning for satellite image classification on DeepSAT-6 dataset.

link for dataset-
https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/deepsat-sat6

My base model is **Resnet50**. 
I am trying to follow this training strategy https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html that is first training the top layer separately based on the output of the completely frozen convolutional layers and then attaching the top with the pre-trained weights and then start unfreezing the convolutional blocks.

top layer-

```
model=Sequential([
Dense(1024,input_dim=2048),
BatchNormalization(),
Activation('relu'),
Dense(256),
BatchNormalization(),
Activation('relu'),
Dense(6, activation='softmax'),
])
```

trained for 50 epochs got training accuracy of around- **95.09**% and cross-Val accuracy- **93.71**%

Then, I attached this top to the convolutional block and unfroze the bottommost conventional block-

Train on 275400 samples, validate on 48600 samples.

```
Epoch 1/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 649s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0962 - accuracy: 0.9656 - val_loss: 6.1452 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
Epoch 2/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 652s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0835 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 5.5609 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
Epoch 3/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 665s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0745 - accuracy: 0.9734 - val_loss: 6.6450 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
Epoch 4/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 663s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0680 - accuracy: 0.9758 - val_loss: 6.4879 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
Epoch 5/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 678s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0634 - accuracy: 0.9775 - val_loss: 6.2436 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
Epoch 6/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 651s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0589 - accuracy: 0.9789 - val_loss: 7.9822 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
Epoch 7/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 662s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0555 - accuracy: 0.9803 - val_loss: 9.0204 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
Epoch 8/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 701s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0521 - accuracy: 0.9812 - val_loss: 8.3389 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
Epoch 9/10
275400/275400 [==============================] - 669s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0502 - accuracy: 0.9824 - val_loss: 8.9311 - val_accuracy: 0.1554
```

So why the cross-validation loss is behaving so oddly? Why isn't it decreasing with the epochs?

Comment: can we have a minimal working example?

Comment: @colt.exe you can check the code out in the GitHub link provided (edits).
PS: I am quite new to coding and deep-learning so I don't know how to write an MWE for this sort of problem, hope you can understand.

Comment: I think your model overfits. Your training loss is decreasing, and the training accuracy is increasing which seems to point to the fact that your neural network is actually learning, but it may be the case that it does not generalize very well. Maybe use some dropout, or reduce the number of layers you have added. You can try to add just one additional layer and see if that solves the problem.